# drag, sort and serialize from different listi with jquery

Tags: jquery, serialization, drag, jquery-ui-sortable

I have different list, I can drag an element from a list to an other list, and when i serialize one of these, i get each element .. the one I dragged from an other list to. 
Problem is when I drag into a sortable-list an element from a non-sortable list, but from a dragged-only list.
when I try to serialize one of the sortable-list, I'm not able to get the id from the draggable-list

for example, how can I serialize this? http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable
if you try.. the element dragged is not serialized.

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
            revert: true
        });
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
            connectToSortable: "#sortable",
            helper: "clone",
            revert: "invalid"
        });
        $( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();

        $('#save').click(function() {
          var $list = $('#sortable').sortable('serialize');
          alert($list);
        });


    });
    </script>



<div id="save">salva</div>
<div class="demo">

<ul id="draggable">
    <li class="ui-state-highlight" id="c_0">Drag me down</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="c_1">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="c_2">Item 2</li>

</ul>

</div><!-- End demo -->
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
var $list = $('#sortable').sortable('serialize');
```

try

```
var $list = $('#sortable').sortable('serialize', {key:'c'});
```

Comment: nevermind... that fixed my problem... but not yours... I'm not sure why it's not working. Seems like it drags into a being a 'child' of the other list and that is causing an issue.. sorry.